# ASUS P8B75-M/CSM fails to recognize 3 or 4 dimms of RAM, also fails when 2 dimms of ram are in the same colored spots

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard

I have had this problem since I built this PC, it is a few days old.

The board is bought from Ebay, there are 4 Super Talent DDR3 memories of the same model, when I put 2 rams together on the CPU side, it boots, the same with one, but when I put the third one, it throws the MemOK! led light, I press ; wait; and nothing; like 30 minutes and it doesn't give a post or anything, it just stays there; I updated the bios to the latest and it keeps happening, the same happens with 3 or 4 rams.

It is an i7 3770, 2 hard drives and 4 rams of 4GB each, making 16GB.

Please help, I would really appreciate it.

Attached image of how I connect the rams.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPe7L.png)

Comment: Run the ASUS Hardware Diagnostics App to find the bad memory.

Comment: Standard question, did you take proper ESD precautions? Touching metal a couple of times does not count. Perhaps whoever you bought the mb from also did not take ESD precautions and broke it.

Comment: @Bib I did take proper ESD precautions, and the mb seller too, bc he's a familiar.